# LWC Navigation/Routing from one page to another

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

we are creating job portal on community using LWC. on community, client/vendor can create candidates, post jobs, view their candidates, jobs etc. We have created LWC for all those stuffs.

Suppose i have two LWC PageA and PageB and i want to navigate/route from PageA to PageB by passing some data/attributes on button click? these pages will be embedded on community.

It will be more helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving Current LWC Component state](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339353/saving-current-lwc-component-state)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) for this use case.

It has different page types you can use, based on your use case, to navigate.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types

Comment: Lightning-navigation doesn't support state property in communities. I wanted to generate LWC page url at run time on button click and redirect to that url.

Comment: If you just want to pass attributes, you can use localstorage, or sessionstorage from browser to do so. While navigating, storage your attributes in storage and when the component loads read those attributes and then delete them from storage.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses LWR and Client-Side Routing.

Create a wildcard route in your lwr.config.json like so:

```
...
routes: [
  {
    "id": "appRoot",
    "path": "/*",
    "rootComponent": "app/router",
    "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/index.html"
  }
]
...
```

Assuming your router is in your "app/router" module.

```
import routes from 'app/routes';
import { createRouter } from 'lwr/router';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Router extends LightningElement {
    router = createRouter({ routes });
}
```

Personally, I like storing my routes in a different module, app/routes:

```
import RouterHandler from 'app/routerHandler';

const routes = [
  {
    id: 'appRoot',
    uri: '/',
    handler: () => RouterHandler('page/home'),
    page: { type: 'appRoot' },
  },
  {
    id: 'demo1',
    uri: '/demo1',
    handler: () => RouterHandler('page/demo1'),
    page: { type: 'demo1' },
  },
  {
    id: 'demo2',
    uri: '/demo2',
    handler: () => RouterHandler('page/demo2'),
    page: { type: 'demo2' },
  },
  {
    id: 'nestedExample',
    uri: '/nested',
    handler: () => RouterHandler('nested/router'),
    page: { type: 'nested' },
    exact: false,
  },
];

export default routes;
```

I have my `app/routerHandler` configured like so:

```
export default function RouterHandler(module) {
    class _RouterHandler {
        callback;

        constructor(callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        dispose() {}

        update() {
            this.callback({
                viewset: {
                    default: () => import(module),
                },
            });
        }
    }

    return { default: _RouterHandler };
}
```

Of course, you can override it on a per module basis, but I use that for about 80% of my routes anyway.

Then what I do for the actual navigating is use a `app/routerLink` module:

```
import routes from 'app/routes';
import { api, wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { navigate, NavigationContext } from 'lwr/navigation';

export default class RouterLink extends LightningElement {
  @api href;
  @api target;
  @api title;
  @api atts = {};
  @api type;

  @wire(NavigationContext) navContext;

  handleClick(event) {
    let route = routes.find((x) => x.uri === this.href);

    if (route) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const pageOptions = route.page;

      if (this.type) {
        pageOptions.type = this.type;
      }

      if (this.atts) {
        pageOptions.attributes = this.atts;
      }

      navigate(this.navContext, pageOptions);
    }
  }
}
```

Its html template:

```
<template>
  <a
    href={href}
    title={title}
    target={target}
    onclick={handleClick}
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </a>
</template>
```

By using an anchor, I can still use this component for routes not inside my app as when the href is not found in the routes, it will fallback to not running event.preventDefault and just use the native callback.

My `app/routerLink` will also work for nested routes as it also checks for the "exact" property, which I won't elaborate but just have the module point to a secondary router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Localstorage to save the state,

Alternatively you could use:
https://github.com/prashantk0001/lwc-router

However using above component will restrict you to create only one page within the community/within every page you might need to register the routes.

It supports queryparameters & pagestate.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in non LWR Communities..

// ----  navigate from page

```
 navigate(pageName,rpsId) {
    try {
        console.log('attempting to nav to pageName:'+pageName + '..rpsId'+rpsId+'.. rsGroupDate='+this.rsGroupDate);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: pageName
            },
            state: {
                rpsId : rpsId,
                rsGroupDate : this.rsGroupDate
            }
        });
        //this._disconnectCb = true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

//--- navigate to page..

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    if (currentPageReference) {
        this._currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
        this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
        if(this.urlStateParameters) {
            this.setParametersBasedOnUrl();
        }
    }
}
```