# Saving Current LWC Component state

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have a list lwc component on page 1.. and details component on page 2

Page 1 has "list component" user decides to filter the list to show only records created the month of May.
users find a line item on that list then selects the button to view details.  We use navigation mixing to navigate the user to page 2 that has the details "details component".

When user hits the back button to return to page 1 ("list component").  Problem is that the component is re initialized and the user has lost the filters they had selected.

Is there a build in way in LWC/Communities to store page previous page component state? or do we have to use something like js sessionStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "built in way" to store this, you can either create an object to store the state, use a record of the object if applicable, or use a browser storage option to restore the state of the view.

[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is supported in lwc, and you also have other options available depending on the amount of data that you need to store.